# Plot KMeans clusters and classification for 1-dimensional data

Tags: python, matplotlib, machine-learning, scikit-learn, k-means

I am using `KMeans` to cluster the three time-series datasets with different characterstics. For reproducibility reasons, I am sharing the data [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=18SdS6NUX3ff334A6G-lJOJYDCppiZaZD).

Here is my code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

protocols = {}

types = {"data1": "data1.csv", "data2": "data2.csv", "data3": "data3.csv"}

for protname, fname in types.items():
    col_time,col_window = np.loadtxt(fname,delimiter=',').T
    trailing_window = col_window[:-1] # "past" values at a given index
    leading_window  = col_window[1:]  # "current values at a given index
    decreasing_inds = np.where(leading_window < trailing_window)[0]
    quotient = leading_window[decreasing_inds]/trailing_window[decreasing_inds]
    quotient_times = col_time[decreasing_inds]

    protocols[protname] = {
        "col_time": col_time,
        "col_window": col_window,
        "quotient_times": quotient_times,
        "quotient": quotient,
    }



k_means = KMeans(algorithm='auto', copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=300,
    n_clusters=3, n_init=10, n_jobs=None, precompute_distances='auto',
    random_state=0, tol=0.0001, verbose=0)
k_means.fit(quotient.reshape(-1,1))
```

This way, given a new data point (with `quotient` and `quotient_times`), I want to know which `cluster` it belongs to by building each dataset stacking these two transformed features `quotient` and `quotient_times` with `KMeans`.

`k_means.labels_` gives this output `array([1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)`

Finally, I want to visualize the clusters using `plt.plot(k_means, ".",color="blue")` but I am getting this error: `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'KMeans'`. How do we plot `KMeans` clusters?

Comment: You don't want to plot the `KMeans` class, right? But instead some numbers. But what numbers do you want to plot? A prediction? The cluster centers?

Comment: I want to have two plots 1) The prediction and 2) The `KMeans` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're effectively looking for is a range of values between which points are considered to be in a given class. It's quite unusual to use KMeans to classify 1d data in this way, although it certainly works. As you've noticed you need to convert your input data to a 2d array in order to use the method.

```
k_means = KMeans(algorithm='auto', copy_x=True, init='k-means++', max_iter=300,
    n_clusters=3, n_init=10, n_jobs=None, precompute_distances='auto',
    random_state=0, tol=0.0001, verbose=0)

quotient_2d = quotient.reshape(-1,1)
k_means.fit(quotient_2d)
```

You will need the `quotient_2d` again for the classification (prediction) step later.

First we can plot the centroids, since the data is 1d the x-axis point is arbitrary.

```
colors = ['r','g','b']
centroids = k_means.cluster_centers_
for n, y in enumerate(centroids):
    plt.plot(1, y, marker='x', color=colors[n], ms=10)
plt.title('Kmeans cluster centroids')
```

This produces the following plot.

[image: cluster centroids]

To get cluster membership for the points, pass `quotient_2d` to `.predict`. This returns an array of numbers for class membership, e.g.

```
>>> Z = k_means.predict(quotient_2d)
>>> Z
array([1, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], dtype=int32)
```

We can use this to filter our original data, plotting each class in a separate color.

```
# Plot each class as a separate colour
n_clusters = 3 
for n in range(n_clusters):
    # Filter data points to plot each in turn.
    ys = quotient[ Z==n ]
    xs = quotient_times[ Z==n ]

    plt.scatter(xs, ys, color=colors[n])

plt.title("Points by cluster")
```

This generates the following plot with the original data, each point coloured by the cluster membership.

[image: points coloured by cluster]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly what you want to plot is the boundary decision of your Kmeans result.
You can find an example of how to do it in scikit-lean website [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/cluster/plot_kmeans_digits.html).

The above example is even doing PCA so the data can be visualize in 2D (if your data dimension is higher than 2) for you it's irrelevant.

You can easily plot your scatter points color by the Kmeans decision so you can better understand where your clustering went wrong.

Comment: I have tried that but I am getting the same error. Does it work out for you?